# Cross compile systemd : cap_init not found

Tags: cross-compiling, configure, autoconf, systemd

I am trying to cross compile systemd-213 for ARM and am getting an error during `configure`

```
checking for library containing dlsym... -ldl
checking sys/capability.h usability... yes
checking sys/capability.h presence... yes
checking for sys/capability.h... yes
checking linux/btrfs.h usability... no
checking linux/btrfs.h presence... no
checking for linux/btrfs.h... no
checking for library containing clock_gettime... -lrt
checking for library containing cap_init... no
configure: error: *** POSIX caps library not found
```

I have already cross compiled libcap and added the directory containing the produced libraries to `LDFLAGS` using `-L` as verified by `echo $LDFLAGS` before calling `configure`.

The error comes from the following line in `configure.ac`

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([cap_init], [cap], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([*** POSIX caps library not found])])
```

I have examined both libcap.a and libcap.so with `objdump -t` and found the entries for cap_init

```
00000108 g     F .text  000000b4 cap_init  <- libcap.a
00001240 g     F .text  000000b4 cap_init  <- libcap.so
```

I don't have much experience with autoconf but I don't see why `cap_init` cannot be found.

I think I have posted the relevant information but I can give more if needed.

Comment: Does library search path contain path to `libcap.so` or `libcap.a`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem but I was crosscompiling `pulseaudio`. The problem was not that `libcap.so` could not be found; the problem was that `libattr.so`, needed by `libcap.so`, could not be found. I saw this in the `config.log` file.
My solution was to add `-lattr` to the `LDFLAGS` environment variable before bootstrapping and configuring.

Answer (score 7):

Got the same error too while compiling systemd-204.   The solution is to execute:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this message:

```
 meson.build:680:8: ERROR:  Problem encountered: POSIX caps headers not found
```

Meant do this first (centos)

```
 yum install libcap-devel
```

Comment: Is there any other option? I did this, but still keep getting the error.

Comment: Fixed it for me, maybe open a new terminal or restart build process?